# How to Use AndroidNineOld to replace fragments with animation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to android programming. I have a main activity that contain some fragments.
I know how to use animations in `android.app.FragmentManager`.

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
            R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out).replace(R.id.layoutToReplace, new ContentFragment()).commit();
```

But when I try to use `android.support.v4.FragmentManager` for some reasons, I realized that it doesn't support `setCustomAnimations()` and it throws the following exception when I use it.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
fm.beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,
            R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out).replace(R.id.layoutToReplace, new ContentFragment()).commit();
```

I Googled my problem and realized that I should use `AndroidOldNine` Library, but I couldn't find a guide for people who are new to programming for android.

Please someone guide me to how to use this library to replace fragments with flipcard animation.

Comment: android.app.FragmentManager doesn't have setCustomAnimation() method,  so what animation are you talking about?

Comment: I used it and it works... `getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out,R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out).replace(R.id.layoutToReplace, new WelcomeScreen()).commit();`

Comment: But it throws exceptions
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out, R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out).replace(R.id.layoutToReplace, new WelcomeScreen()).commit();

Comment: Please add your code snippets and a description to your question via the edit button. It's much more readable this way.

Comment: support library uses Animation(s), not Animator(s)

Comment: @SteveBenett I add it to post

Comment: @pskink I changed `animator` folder name to `anim` but the problem doesn't solve

Comment: what do you have in anim folder?

Comment: @pskink I used this xml files: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html

Comment: its Animator,  not Animation,  see <objectAnimator>

Comment: @pskink So what should i do to use flipcard animation for replace fragments in lower apis?

Comment: i have no idea,  google for it,  i found in two minutes that one https://github.com/genzeb/flip/blob/master/src/com/tekle/oss/android/animation/FlipAnimation.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a single straight way to do this... don't bother your self and skip low android APIs if you need to use `animator`